# I have difficulty to get final concat dataframe by try except for pymssql

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, try-except, pymssql, read-sql

```
for i in Com_Tables:
try:
    frames = [pd.read_sql(f"SELECT * FROM {i}", conn).assign(ComId_Code = i)]

except:
    pass

finally:
    dfxilnex = pd.concat(frames)
```

i am expecting output to concat all data from each item in list however the result is showing only data for last item in list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not appending anything so there is nothing to concatnate. try this:

```
frames = []
for i in Com_Tables:
    try:
        frames.append(pd.read_sql(f"SELECT * FROM {i}", conn).assign(ComId_Code = i))

    except:
        pass

dfxilnex = pd.concat(frames)
```

Comment: this solutions works beautifully...thanks @Serge_de_Gosson_de_Varennes

Comment: @ZulH Glad it helped! Don't forget to accept and/or upvote the answer when you can.